# how to remove the <br/> using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

how to get value without `<br/>` tag using regex n java?

my String is:

```
<Div>
  West Newton, MA 02465
    <br/>USA
</Div>
```

output should be like:

```
West Newton, MA 02465
USA
```

my pattern is like:

```
Pattern p8 = Pattern
                .compile("<div class=\"leftLabel\">Nickname</div>\\s+<div class=\"rightContent\">([^<]*)</div>");
Matcher m8 = p8.matcher(responseBody);
```

i didnt get anything as result. what i have to put there(instead of ([^<]*)).

How?

Comment: Your output does not show `<div>` either - should the regular expression strip all markup or just `<br/>`?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38648319/4695110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of all the tags in the string you can match:

```
<[^>]*>
```

and replace it with `''`

Comment: `i broke<!-- 3<π -->your replaceAll`

Comment: Here's a full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38648319/4695110

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you need regex for it?

why not just remove all tags, e. g. replace '`<br/>`' with "" or "\n", as you like?

Comment: Fun fact, here's the full source for `String#replaceAll`: `public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) { return  Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement); }`. Simple replacement is just fine though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String fixedString = badString.replaceAll("<br\s*/>", "");
```

Comment: `i broke<br      />your replaceAll`

Answer (score 1):

```
replaceAll("<br */>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
String fixedString = badString.replaceAll("<br(.*?\/?)>", "");
```

I think this expression will solve the problem.
It matches with both line-break combinations.

`<br>` and `<br/>`, even with spaces inside them.